Disable cookiebot in google tag manager
I want to replace cmp cookiebot on my company's website with our own code to manage cookies , i paused the cookiebot tags in google tag manager , but i still see the cookiebot code in the code source of my website , i've made sure it's not coded from hubspot or wordpress, and this causes conflicts with my new banner and makes it not work. Thanks in advance for any ideas how can i disable completely the cookiebot.
I've only tried to pause the cookiebot tags in gtm , and check if the issue is from hubspot or else , but i don't have any other ideas.

There are some simple general debugging steps that you have to take to debug any kind of case similar to this, when you see something in your DOM and need to find the source.

Make sure your rogue element is not in the source of the page. Ctrl+U. If it's there, then it comes from the backend. In your case, most likely either some CMS plugin or template. You can also disable JS, reload the page and check if the element is there. Same thing effectively as checking the source.
If it's not there, then it's added dynamically. Open your devtools, go to network request blocking and block GTM. Your work in GTM pausing tags is never trustworthy. Block the whole library and check if it's still there. If it disappears, you know that you made mistake pausing the tags. Go finish the job. If not, then repeat for other similar scripts who can do arbitrary document writes.
Now if the element is still there even after disabling the TMSes, you can go to the Search function of devtools. It's in the drawer. Same place where the network request blocker is. The Search tab allows you to search through the source of all loaded JS. Start searching. For parts of your element that can somewhat uniquely identify it.

This allows you to locate practically all of the unhidden resources. If you need more, you can start looking into inspecting pieces of code that do atob(), btoa(), eval() and whatever uses the Function constructor. But now we're really stepping into the world of front-end malice. I doubt a cookie banner would employ anything close to that.
